# Llenar un campo con la información de otro en grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

al momento de agregar tengo un `select` (color rojo) y lo que deseo es que cuando se seleccione información de este se autocomplete la información en otro campo (color verde), no se si sea posible esto hacerlo en Grocery Crud muchas gracias a todos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede con Grocery-Crud pero el codigo es muy extenso, (mas de lo normal  si lo hicieras directo con un Jquery).

Si lo deseas te paso el codigo Jquery llamandolo desde el back de Codeigniter.

Saludos DTB.

Comment: Muchas gracias de echo lo resolví como mencionas con un jQuery.

Comment: Perfecto, Estamos para servirle. Saludos DTB